# TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I built out a python script the retrieves data from Auth0 and publish it to Ms-sql but im getting errors

```py
 for d in data:
        print d["email"], d["created_at"],d["last_login"],d["last_ip"] #this part worked great
        SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Auth0_stg] "
                      "([Email],[created_at],[last_login],[last_ip]) "
                      " VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
        Values = d["email"],d['created_at'],d['last_login'],d['last_ip']

        cursor.executemany(SQLCommand,Values)
        cursor.commit()
```

When I did the print statements,

```
d['email'], d['last_login']
```

everything printed great.  but when i used SQL commands to try to populate my table, it returns this error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1454, in execute
    raise TypeError("Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row")
TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row
```

Any suggestions/insights appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executemany` executes the same request several times with different parameters. Because of that it is expecting a sequence as second parameter (such as a list of list, or a list of tuples...)

In your code you only want to do a single request for each iteration of your `for` loop. Replace `executemany` by `execute` and it should work fine.

EDIT: For your second issue, before the line:

```
Values = d["email"],d['created_at'],d['last_login'],d['last_ip']
```

You can fill the empty values with a for loop:

```
for key in ["email", "created_at", "last_login", "last_ip"]:
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = ""
```

EDIT 2: To create a datetime object from a string, you can use `strptime()`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_str_date = "2016-10-18T20:15:45.454Z"
>>> my_datetime = datetime.strptime(my_str_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
>>> print(my_datetime)
2016-10-18 20:15:45.454000
```

You can then format it using `strftime()`:

```
>>> print(my_datetime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
2016/10/18 20:15:45
```

Comment: i tried using `execute`, but now its returning   `Values = d["email"],d["created_at"],d["last_login"],d["last_ip"]
KeyError: 'last_login'`

Comment: @MCO that is a different issue, there is no value for the key `last_login` in `d`.

Comment: how do I set it so that when its empty, it will populate either a ' ' or null?

Comment: thank you! one more question, how can i convert something like this to a datetime format in SQL?
2016-10-18T20:15:46.454Z
to '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @MCO You could use `strftime()`: `my_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: i got an error  date = d['created_at'].strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Did you figure it out? It probably means `d['created_at']` is a string instead of a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 3):

Note the difference between [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

> `.execute ( operation [, parameters ])`
>
> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation.

and [`cursor.executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany):

> `.executemany ( operation , seq_of_parameters )`
>
> Prepare a database operation (query or command) and then **execute it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence** seq_of_parameters .

So, if you are executing your query for only **one** set of values, call it like this:

```
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Auth0_stg] "
              "([Email],[created_at],[last_login],[last_ip]) "
              " VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
Values = ['email','created_at','last_login''last_ip']

cursor.executemany(SQLCommand,[Values])
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: What is the point of using `executemany()` to execute a single query? +1 for the explanations though

Comment: user may have multiple values insert, that's the reason i dint change from `executemany` to `execute`.

Comment: thank you! one more question, how can i convert something like this to a datetime format in SQL? 2016-10-18T20:15:46.454Z to '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'